# ireport delete the class of a textFieldExpression

Tags: class, jasper-reports, ireport

i have something like this on my jrxml file on all the textFieldExpressions:

```
<textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{Cia_par}+":"]]></textFieldExpression>
```

then I change some positions of some fields and save, then the ireport made some changes on the textFieldExpressions like:

```
<textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Cia_par}+":"]]></textFieldExpression>
```

the class is been deleted, what can i do to avoid this everytime  i save?

Comment: What version of *iReport* are you using? And why do you need the class attribute for *textField*?

Comment: I'm using 5.6.0, and tes I need the class attribute, because this is mandatory on the testing server that my team is using